# individuating rows based on conditions in nested data

Tags: r, nested, row

I am new to r, and I am having some trouble manipulating the data in the way I need it for my analysis. I would be grateful if anyone could help, because this is essential for my research.

I already asked a similar question but the answer I got did not fully address my problem, I will try to be more clear this time to see if anyone can help.

my data looks something like this:

```
df<- data.frame(
"Reporter" = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA","USA"),
"Partner" = c( "EU", "EU","EU","EU", "EU","EU"), 
"Product.cat" = c("1", "11", "111", "112", "12", "2"), 
"Product Description" = c("Food", "Fruit", "Apple", 
"Banana", "Meat", "Manifactured"),
"Year" = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970), 
"trade value" = c( 100, 50, 30, 20, 50, 220), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I have country-year observations about trade. 
The vector *'product.cat'* indicates what kind of commodity is exported. The more digits the *product.cat* has, the more the trade information is disaggregated. 
For example *product.cat.* 111 (eg. apple) and 112 (e.g. bananas) are sub-product categories of product category 11 (e.g. fruit). 
The same holds for the higher levels of aggregation. Product category 11 (fruit) is a subcategory of *product.cat* 1(food) together with *product.cat* 12 (meat).
To note that data in lower categories is nested in higher level of aggregation. Hence the value of *product.cat* 11 (50) is equal to the value of *product.cat* 111 (30) + *product.cat* 112 (20).

To do my analysis I need to identify those values that are not reported at the most disaggregated possible level - i.e. **I need to identify the data not reported at the 3 digit level.**

My problem is that for some country-year observation I have data reported accurately at all levels of aggregation (e.g. 1,11,111,112) while for others i only have data at the higher level of aggregation (e.g. 12 and 2). For instance, in my example, I only have *product.cat* 12 (meat), but not data on what kind of meat *product.cat* 121(pork), *product.cat* 122 (veal). 
Similarly, in the example, data on *product.cat* 2 (manufacturing), is not reported at lower levels. 
we do not know whether is *product.cat* 21 (clothing) or *product.cat* 22 (wood products).

In other words, I have data reported at the 2 digit (12) or first digit level (2) that could be reported at the 3 digit level. **To note that every category should be disaggregated at the 3 level digit**

- *What I would like to do is to find a way to individuate all the data* ***exclusively*** *reported at a higher level of aggregation and* ***change their product.cat name adding an "m" to the end.***
- *After manipulation the* product.cat 12 should become* **12m** *to indicate that data was reported only at the 2nd digit. 
  Similarly I would like to identify exports that are reported* **only** *at the first digit. product.cat 2 should become* **2mm** *to reflect that the data was reported only at the first digit.*

To be sure, only the data for which I have information exclusively at a higher level of aggregation - i.e. in the example 12 and 2 - should include "m"s. 
For instance, in the example, I do not want to have 1mm, since I have data at a lower level of aggregation (11,12). Similarly, I do not want to have 11m, because I have data at lower levels of aggregation (111,112). What I would like to have is 12m and 2mm because the data is reported only at a higher level of aggregation (12 and 2).

I know that this is a very specific question but I would really appreciate if anyone could help.

**Note**: in the real dataset, due to for measurement errors, the sum of the disaggregated values do not always perfectly add up to the higher level of aggregation. (for instance, 111+112 can be > 11). Hence, ideally to solve the issue the, I am looking to a function that is able to specify when to add the m based on the number of digits divided by country, partner, year, rather than the sum of the traded value.

I really thank everyone that could give me a help with this, it would be a huge step forward for my research.

---- attempts

I have been working on this function, but it does not seem to do what I am looking for. Maybe someone can find out what is going wrong

```
fillLevel <- function(x, width = 3, fill = "m"){
sp <- split(x, substr(x, 1, 1))
sp <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
n <- nchar(sp[[i]])
if(all(n < 3)){
  j <- which(n == max(n))
  sp[[i]][j] <- gsub(" ", "m", formatC(sp[[i]][j], width = -3))
}
sp[[i]]
})
unname(unlist(sp))
}

df <- df%>% mutate(prdcat2 = fillLevel(df$Product.cat.))
```

As you can see it only individuates 2mm but not *12m*. Moreover when I run it on more complex codes it mess up the order of my data. I think this relates to `sp <- lapply(seq_along(sp)` but i am not sure how to go about it.

Best

Comment: Could you post an example of what you want the final result to look like?  It's a complicated questions and I don't think I get it.

Comment: Sure, the final result should individuate the data that is not reported at the third digit. hence 1, 11, 111, 112, 12m, 2mm

Comment: You could use the igraph package to enter the Product.cat data into a tree structure and flag all terminal nodes having fewer than three digits / being at depth less than three. Alternately, I've never used it, but data.tree looks useful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# tag levels
df[, lvl := nchar(Product.cat)]
df[lvl < 3L, has_subcat := FALSE]

# use level-3 observations to flag level-2s as okay    
df[
  df[lvl == 3, .(Reporter, Partner, Year, Product.cat = substr(Product.cat, 1, 2))],
  on=.(Reporter, Partner, Year, Product.cat),
  has_subcat := TRUE
]

# use level-2 observations to flag level-1s as okay    
df[
  df[lvl == 2, .(Reporter, Partner, Year, Product.cat = substr(Product.cat, 1, 1))],
  on=.(Reporter, Partner, Year, Product.cat),
  has_subcat := TRUE
]

# create new cat, flagging observations with no subcategories
df[, newcat := Product.cat]
df[has_subcat == FALSE, newcat := paste0(Product.cat, strrep("m", 3-lvl))]

   Reporter Partner Product.cat Product.Description Year trade.value lvl has_subcat newcat
1:      USA      EU           1                Food 1970         100   1       TRUE      1
2:      USA      EU          11               Fruit 1970          50   2       TRUE     11
3:      USA      EU         111               Apple 1970          30   3         NA    111
4:      USA      EU         112              Banana 1970          20   3         NA    112
5:      USA      EU          12                Meat 1970          50   2      FALSE    12m
6:      USA      EU           2        Manifactured 1970         220   1      FALSE    2mm
```

I'm assuming that this should be done separately per Reporter-Partner-Year.

Comment: Frank, you are a genius, this is awesome!!! thank you very much. However, is there a way to make it work at least for multiple reporter-partner at the same time? I have over 20million observation in my true data! I am trying to use your code on a slightly larger sample and it seems to work. Why do you say I should do it separately for each Reporter-Partner-Year?

Comment: @Alessandro Glad it's helpful :) I was just thinking that the data is collected per Reporter-Partner-Year, so the data should be checked at that level, but if a given Reporter-Partner always provides the same category levels in every year, you could remove that part of the logic in the answer and I think it should still work. Let me know if you find any bugs/problems with this approach. I am curious since I sometimes have to deal with similar data.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed correct, the data is collected per Reporter-Partner-Year. But playing around with fictitious and simple dataset with multiple Reporter-Partner-Year your code seems to be able to pick up the different levels. I will play more with your code and let you know whether something emerges. But it really looks like you have solved a problem I have been trying to deal with for quite a while!! Thanks again. Do let me know if there is something I haven't picked up yet that makes the code unable to distinguish different  Reporter-Partner-Year.